# how can i group-by-multiple-fields-using-angular-filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'},
  {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'}
];
```

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: '[team,age]'">
    Group name: {{ key }}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="player in value">
        player: {{ player.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is my script when i run it i got the answer in {{key}} parameter is team,age
I want the team and age both as a separate key how can i achieve this
I tried so many methods but I didn't get any result. Can anyone help me out how to do this?

Comment: you don't have age coloumn in $scope.players array and you are trying to groupBy with team,age

Comment: thank u for your time but i solved it

Comment: You can put your answer here

Comment: ok so if i want both team and name as a separate key i can use 
value[0].name
value[0].team
just like that